# Drm protected Video lagging when played offline on 2x speed

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, drm, widevine

I am trying to play drm protected video which is downloaded. It is working fine on most of the device. It is lagging on tablet devices specifically on Samsung A7 tab(Smt-500).

When I am playing file from server the lagging very less visible but when I play offline video on 2x speed lagging is quite visible.

I am using exoplayer - 2.10.2. I am using following datasource factory.

For online:

```
val defaultHttpDataSourceFactory =
    DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(userAgent, defaultBandwidthMeter)

val mediaDataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(
    context,
    defaultBandwidthMeter,
    defaultHttpDataSourceFactory
)


dashMediaSource=DashMediaSource.Factory(mediaDataSourceFactory)
    .createMediaSource(videoViewModel.uri)
```

for offline:

```
cacheDataSourceFactory = CacheDataSourceFactory(cache, factory)

                    
dashMediaSource = DashMediaSource.Factory(videoViewModel.cacheDataSourceFactory)
                        .createMediaSource(videoViewModel.uri

)
```

Comment: Have you tested the same video both protected and unprotected to check it really is the encryption that is making the difference? If it is then you may find also that the results will be different on different devices, depending on their HW and SW specifications.

Comment: @Mick Yes tested unprotected video works fine